# Comment reply system with React Quill and Firebase Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, quill, rte

I'm making a comment system with React Quill as my editor and Firebase Firestore. Each comment post gets stored in firestore. Each stored comment has a reply button, and when clicked, the editor should be populated with the comment content I want to reply to. Basically I need to populate my editor with the content stored in firestore database. Here's a screenshot as to watch I want to achieve:

[Comment reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylZyB.png)

Here's some code from the comment editor component

```
class NewComment extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  comment: {
    commentID: "",
    content: "",
    createDate: new Date(),
    featureImage: "",
    isPublish: "True",
    createUserID: "",
  },
};
}
 ...
onChangeCommentContent = (value) => {
 this.setState({
  comment: {
    ...this.state.comment,
    content: value,
  },
});
};
...
render() {
 return (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col xl={9} lg={8} md={8} sn={12}>
        <h2 className={classes.SectionTitle}>Comment</h2>

        <FormGroup>
          <ReactQuill
            ref={(el) => (this.quill = el)}
            value={this.state.comment.content}
            onChange={(e) => this.onChangeCommentContent(e)}
            theme="snow"
            modules={this.modules}
            formats={this.formats}
            placeholder={"Enter your comment"}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>...
```

The reply button is in a different component where I render the stored comments. Tell me if you need the full code from the components.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can't you just use the `content` of the comment to compose the `value` of the `ReactQuill` component?

Comment: I did try that. Problem I had with that is that the `onChangeCommentContent()` ends up rewriting the `content` state when I enter something in the reply. I also tried to create a new `repliedTo` property in `this.state.comment` and set it to the comment that I want to reply to content. The problem I had with that is I couldn't figure out how to set `repliedTo` state by clicking on a button that is in a separate  component called `<Comments/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a simple example on how to pass on information between two components via the parent component using function components](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-forked-kdy4q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```js
// Index.js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [replyValue, setReplyValue] = useState("");

  const onClick = (value) => {
    setReplyValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Comment value="This is a reply" onClick={onClick} />
      <Comment value="This is another reply" onClick={onClick} />
      <CreateReply quoteValue={replyValue} />
    </>
  );
};

// Comment.js
export const Comment = ({ value, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="comment" onClick={() => onClick(value)}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};

// CreateReply.js
export const CreateReply = ({ quoteValue = "" }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(quoteValue);
  }, [quoteValue]);

  const onValueUpdated = (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== value) {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactQuill value={value} onChange={onValueUpdated} />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Here is the same example using class components](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-forked-v8iet):

```
// Index.js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      replyValue: ""
    };
  }

  onClick = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      replyValue: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Comment value="This is a reply" onClick={this.onClick} />
        <Comment value="This is another reply" onClick={this.onClick} />
        <CreateReply quoteValue={this.state.replyValue} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Comment.js
export class Comment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="comment"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.value)}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// CreateReply.js
export class CreateReply extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onValueUpdated = this.onValueUpdated.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      value: props.quoteValue
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.quoteValue !== prevProps.quoteValue) {
      this.setState({
        value: this.props.quoteValue
      });
    }
  }

  onValueUpdated = (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({
        value: newValue
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ReactQuill value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onValueUpdated} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I understand you are using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks in this example. Sadly I haven't gotten around to learning hooks yet and my project already uses class components, and to my knowledge, you can't use hooks in class components. How can I achieve this same result in your example using class component?

Comment: No worries, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-forked-v8iet) you can find the same example but using class components. I've also updated my answer to include this.

Comment: @rokajova if my answer was helpful, you can also vote it up. [Voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote), as it boosts my reputation on StackOverflow!

Comment: Yes I did thank you very much fo the help! But it looks like my voting isn't appearing publicly yet, my reputation score is too low :(

Comment: Ah yes indeed, no worries! Enjoy StackOverflow!